# Codeignitere route regex 404

Tags: regex, codeigniter, url-routing

I'm trying to make dynamic route for user pages. My route config looks next:

```
$route['id[0-9+]'] = 'user/index/$1';
```

On my Mac with MAMP it works fine. I can access to user's page with next uri (for example):

`http://localhost:8888/MySite/id1`

But the same uri doesn't work on the server and on my partner's windows-machine. I can access to page with `user/index/1` and all another static routes works fine. I think there is a problem with regular expression, but I can't figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'id[0-9]+'
```

I guess you mean this.This will match `id87` or `id67723`.

`id[0-9+]` will match `id9+` or `id8` or `id+`

Comment: Really it works now! Thanks. Can you explain why my version works on local machine if it's not correct?

Comment: @VladislavKovalyov it work until id has only one digit after it.like `id1` or `id2` or `id9`.You might be havingsingle digit id's on your local machine.